# vba do until loop doesn't go in although condition is valid

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I won't bring the entire code, I'll try to show what is relevant.
The following code (which is inside a loop, but it doesn't matter) calls a function (compareStrings) which returns an integer.

```
Sheet1.Range("S" & i).Value = compareStrings(sheet1.Range("J" & i).Value, sheet1.Range("K" & i).Value)
```

So basically I have a loop that fills column S with integers.
I then sort S column in ascending order.
later I have another loop, that is supposed to do something with all the values that are less than 5.

The loop looks like this:

```
With Sheet1.Range("S" & i)
    Do Until .Value < 5
        If .Value = 0 Then
            'some statement
        Else
            'some statement
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End With
```

For some reason it doesn't go in the loop although I have many rows with values that are < 5. I actually tried to change it to <> and it doesn't go in either. It is as if it doesn't see it as an integer, although I have put integers in these cells.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What does the value show up as? I think we will need to see more code.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't much for us to help you with without seeing the raw data. I would suggest placing a `Debug.Print .Value` statement and watching the immediate window.

Comment: @SJR it shows numbers. If I manually calculate something with these numbers it works (for example =s1 +s2). I don't know what other code might be relevant. I show everything I do with this column..

Comment: Are you sure you want `<` in `Do Until .Value < 5` - i.e. if the value is less than 5, *stop and don't do anything*? Your logic doesn't seem to make sense, especially if the values are in ascending order.

Comment: Use F8 to step through the code line by line, checking the values of the variables as you go, and you'll figure out exactly where the issue lies.  See Chip Pearson's [**Debugging VBA**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

Comment: I think you actually mean `Do Until i < 5`

Comment: the snippet we have is not really looping through a range, so this seems like it'd be an infinite loop if `.Value` started at < 5

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 no infinite loop - nothing would happen.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I noticed that too. `i` is being incremented in the `Do` loop, but the with statement referencing the `i` is outside the loop....

Comment: @BigBen oops, I mean if `.Value` started at `> 5`, how would it know to leave that loop unless that's part of her else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I have another loop that is supposed to do something with all the values that are less than 5."

Your logic doesn't make sense though.

`Do Until .Value < 5` will *not* do anything with values less than 5. It's the same as saying "take action if my value is *greater than or equal to* 5.

`Do While` might be a better option.